# Cmd closes when running flutter doctor or flutter version code in cmd

Tags: flutter, cmd, flutter-doctor

I setup flutter. C:\flutter.
I added path: C:\flutter\bin
but Cmd closes when running flutter doctor or flutter version code in cmd.

how can fix this problem?

Comment: Use cmd as an administrator and if this doesn't work, Reinstall flutter. But  from what I think you might have placed the path in wrong area. good luck

Comment: hi , please using the `flutter doctor -v` command, which can  help identify any issues with your Flutter setup. I recommend attaching the results of this command to your question to help the community assist you in finding a solution.